# Using project using Namespaces with existing code

Tags: php, machine-learning, namespaces

I am trying to integrate PHPML with an existing project. PHPML uses namespaces and I have little experience using them.

I am able to run PHPML directly through my controller however when integrating it in to a class method I get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in... on line 4
```

My class method:

```
class learn{
  public function return_adjustments(){
    include 'application/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares;
    use Phpml\Exception\FileException;

    $samples = $this->csv_to_array('samples.csv');
    $targets = $this->csv_to_array('targets.csv');

    $regression = new LeastSquares();
    $regression->train($samples, $targets);
}
```

Is it possible to do this correctly? I'm struggling on the concept of namespaces.

Comment: You are breaking the rules of the `importing` in PHP, checkout the right scope of [`use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "use" statements at the very top of your file in order to import them properly.

```
include 'application/vendor/autoload.php';

class learn{
  public function return_adjustments() {

    $samples = $this->csv_to_array('samples.csv');
    $targets = $this->csv_to_array('targets.csv');

    $regression = new Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares();
    $regression->train($samples, $targets);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, however, it throws Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'LeastSquares' not found in

Comment: What happens if you try `$regression = new Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares();`? Depending on if this throws an exception too, chances are the autoload mechanism doesn't work properly

Comment: Of course! Works perfectly. If you'd like to change your answer ill accept it! Thank you!